# Controller is not going inside the condition if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView )

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

in my iphone app i have implimented **`UISearchDisplayController`** , while searching inside the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method controller is not going inside the condition

```
 if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView )
```

I have added the `UISearchDisplayController` in the XIB and added `UISearchDisplayDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate` delegates in xib,,can any one tell me why the controller is not going inside

Comment: Did you get the solution of this prob?? i m too stuck on this

Answer (score 0):

`tableView` is not equal to `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`

Either remove the if-statement or set your `tableView` equal to `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTablevView`

If you have multiple table views, you probably forgot to connect your search results table to the appropriate delegate and datasource.